# Stopword removal and save the new file

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, split, pattern-matching

I have text files which I need to remove stop words from them.  I have the stop words stored in a text file.  I load the "stop-word" text file into my Perl script and store the stop words in an array called "stops".

Currently I am loading a different set of text files and I am storing them in a separate array then doing a pattern match to see if any of the words are indeed stop words.
I can print the stop words and know which ones are occurring in the files but how do I remove them from the text file and store a new text file so it has no stop words?

i.e Stopwords:
the
a
to
of
and
into

Text File:
"The girl was driving and crashed into a man"

Resulting file:
girl was driving crashed man

I load the file in:

```
$dirtoget = "/Users/j/temp/";
opendir( IMD, $dirtoget ) || die("Cannot open directory");`
@thefiles = readdir(IMD);`

foreach $f (@thefiles) {
if ( $f =~ m/\.txt$/ ) {

    open( FILE, "/Users/j/temp/$f" ) or die "Cannot open FILE";

    while (<FILE>) {
        @file = <FILE>;
```

Here is the pattern matching loop:

```
  foreach $word(split) {
                foreach $x (@stop) {
                   if  ($x =~ m/\b\Q$word\E\b/) {
                 $word='';
                        print $word,"\n";
```

Setting `$word` to be null.

Or I could do:

```
    $word = '' if exists $stops{$word};
```

I'm just not sure how I set output file to no longer contain the matching words.
Is it stupid to store the words which don't match in an array and output them to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwriting the files in-place is possible, but a hassle. The Unix way of doing this is to just output the non-stopwords to standard output (which `print` does by default), redirect that

```
./remove_stopwords.pl textfile.txt > withoutstopwords.txt
```

then proceed with the file `withoutstopwords.txt`. This also allows the use of the program in a pipeline.

Comment: that will print all the words that have to be removed but how do I remove them from the original file?

Comment: `mv withoutstopwords.txt textfile.txt`. Or save them in an array, then write them out.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw<$LIST_SEPARATOR $NR>;

my $stop_regex 
    = do { 
        local $LIST_SEPARATOR = '\\E|\\Q';
        eval "qr/\\b(\\Q@{stop}\\E)\\b/";
    };
@ARGV = glob( '/Users/j/temp/*.txt' );
while ( <> ) { 
    next unless m/$stop_regex/;
    print "Stop word '$1' found at $ARGV line $NR\n";
}
```

What *do* you want to do with these words? If you wanted to replace them then you could do this:

```
use English qw<$INPLACE_EDIT $LIST_SEPARATOR $NR>;
local $INPLACE_EDIT = 'bak';

...
while ( <> ) { 
    if ( m/$stop_regex/ )
        s/$stop_regex/$something_else/g;
    }
    print;
}
```

With `$INPLACE_EDIT` active, perl will dump the print into a '.bak' file and when it moves onto the next file, it will write the `.bak` to the original file. *If* that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [substitution operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html) to delete words from your files:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @stop = qw(foo bar);
while (<DATA>) {
    my $line = $_;
    $line =~ s/\b$_\b//g for @stop;
    print $line;
}

__DATA__
here i am
with a foo
and a bar too
lots of foo foo food
```

prints:

```
here i am
with a
and a  too
lots of   food
```